# PHP/SQL Display Link Results

Tags: php, html

I've created a link

```
echo '<a href="description.php?id='.$dash.'" >'."<strong>$name</strong>".'</a>';
```

which works, but takes me to a blank page (description.php)

this is the code i tried, nothing displays.

```
if (isset($_GET['$name'])) { 
 $result = $_GET['$name'];

$sql = "SELECT PedalID, Manufacturer, ProductName FROM PedalDirectory";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["PedalID"]. " - Name: " . $row["ProductName"]. " " . $row["Manufacturer"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();

}
```

Can anyone offer some insight as to why this code isn't displaying a result?

Comment: What's the relation to  `css`?

Comment: You're using $_GET['name'] instead of $_GET['id'] and you also not using it in your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your link is sending `$_GET['id']` but you are referencing `$_GET['$name']`

Your code should be

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['id'])) { 
    $result = $_GET['id'];

    $sql = "SELECT PedalID, Manufacturer, ProductName FROM PedalDirectory";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "id: " . $row["PedalID"]. " - Name: " . $row["ProductName"]. " " . $row["Manufacturer"]. "<br>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks all. I got it now